# Chrome's changing height when loading pictures - how to get actual height with jQuery on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have the following:

```
var offset = {top: target.offset().top + target.height() + 3,
                  left: target.offset().left};
target.offset(offset);
```

this happens on `$(document).ready(..)`

However, in chrome, the target object is not positioned with the appropriate height. When I placed an `alert(..)` to show the actual height, I saw the reason - `target.offset().top` returns less than desired because at that moment an image still isn't loaded (the alert blocks the loading of the page and this becomes visible).

I fixed the issue by specifying an explicit `height` of the `<div>` around the image, but is there a better way?

Comment: Give width (and height) attributes to the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$(document).ready(..)`, use `$(window).load(...)` for this :)

The window `onload` event doesn't happen until *after* images are finished loading, so that's what you want in these cases.